# how to implement current plan on calendar date basis in Airflow

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there any way to implement current plan concept in Airflow..

```
Example: In Control m jobs will be scheduled as per date example: ODATE : 20200801
```

But in airflow we are not able to see an option how to schedule the jobs as per every date/calendar..

Is there any best way we can implement..

Comment: I did not get you. Do you want to run it once a day ?

Comment: You want to run your job on a date of every month then you can use crontab entry in schedule_interval.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies...

Comment: We want to run once in a day. Lets say if we have any environmental issue and jobs will not be executed -- In this case in control m we can hold the particular ODATE but where as in Airflow we need to pause the dag.. If the issue has crossed more than 24hrs then one of the day plan will be skipped .. How can we acheive that in airflow so that , we dont want to miss any of the day plan like we have in control m